# Using memcpy to copy BYTE array parts into AnsiString

Tags: c++, arrays, memcpy, ansistring

Got following situation:

```
AnsiString IP_Adress;
int Port;
BYTE ReadBuffer[2048];
```

using this works perfect:

```
memcpy(&Port, &ReadBuffer[48],1);
```

for reading out Potnummer i need two Bytes, so Port content after memcpy is:
    Port == 5000;

But using the same method for AnsiString fails:

```
memcpy(&IP_Adress, &ReadBuffer[44],3);
```

after that the IP_Adress isn´t empty but doesn´t contain the same as ReadBuffer:

```
ReafBuffer[44] == 192
ReafBuffer[45] == 168
ReafBuffer[46] == 123
ReafBuffer[47] == 240
```

content of IP_Adress position 0-3:

0x27 0xEC 0x77 0x00

Comment: Huh.. This doesn't seem right. The Port memcpy should be `sizeof(int)`, which is probably 4 or 8. A memcpy of just 1 byte shouldn't work right.

Comment: with sizeof you say how many elements of want to copy. if you limit the number exactly you what you want

Comment: But the remaining Port bytes have an undefined value. memcpy should be `memcpy(dest, src, sizeof(type) * N)`, where N is the number of elements. Since `sizeof(int)` is greater than 1, you don't copy a whole integer.

Comment: Not sure to understand what you mean. But the size of port ist larger than 1 and it still works. N ist the number of BYTES i want to copy, in my case.

Comment: You're copying from index 44-47 in `ReadBuffer` into `IP_Address`, so it's not surprising the result is different from the contents of 48- 51.

Comment: Look up `ntohs` for port number.

Comment: Don´t know why i wrote it wrong. corrected it now. ntohs? what is that?

Comment: Well, [look it up](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohs).

Comment: Port works and IP_Address doesn´t. Why should I look something up for PORT?